# Get data to be usable

Tags: r, xml, xml2

I have been trying to get the data from this link to be usable

```r
url <- "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1061165/0001567619-21-010580.txt"
```

that should be the same information as the one on this link
https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1061165/000156761921010580/xslForm13F_X01/form13fInfoTable.xml

I have been able to download the file into a .txt, but can not get the data

Thanks

Comment: Please define usable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file appears to be two nested XML files. We can extract each of the components into `list`s with this code:

```r
txt <- readLines("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1061165/0001567619-21-010580.txt")
grep("</?XML>", txt)
# [1]  46 101 109 719
txt[grep("</?XML>", txt)]
# [1] "<XML>"  "</XML>" "<XML>"  "</XML>"
```

A brief inspection of the file informed that `grep`, suggesting that an XML file started and stopped, and then another started/stopped. If we stay *within* that, we can extract most of the data with

```r
library(xml2)
first <- as_list(read_xml(paste(txt[47:100], collapse = "")))
str(first)
# List of 1
#  $ edgarSubmission:List of 2
#   ..$ headerData:List of 2
#   .. ..$ submissionType:List of 1
#   .. .. ..$ : chr "13F-HR"
#   .. ..$ filerInfo     :List of 4
#   .. .. ..$ liveTestFlag  :List of 1
#   .. .. .. ..$ : chr "LIVE"
#   .. .. ..$ flags         :List of 3
#   .. .. .. ..$ confirmingCopyFlag  :List of 1
#   .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr "false"
#   .. .. .. ..$ returnCopyFlag      :List of 1
#   .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr "true"
#   .. .. .. ..$ overrideInternetFlag:List of 1
#   .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr "false"
#   .. .. ..$ filer         :List of 1
#   .. .. .. ..$ credentials:List of 2
#   .. .. .. .. ..$ cik:List of 1
#   .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr "0001061165"
#   .. .. .. .. ..$ ccc:List of 1
#   .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr "XXXXXXXX"
#   .. .. ..$ periodOfReport:List of 1
#   .. .. .. ..$ : chr "03-31-2021"
#   ..$ formData  :List of 3
```

and the second batch:

```r
second <- as_list(read_xml(paste(txt[110:718], collapse = "")))
str(second)
# List of 1
#  $ informationTable:List of 38
#   ..$ infoTable:List of 7
#   .. ..$ nameOfIssuer        :List of 1
#   .. .. ..$ : chr "ADOBE SYSTEMS INCORPORATED"
#   .. ..$ titleOfClass        :List of 1
#   .. .. ..$ : chr "COM"
#   .. ..$ cusip               :List of 1
#   .. .. ..$ : chr "00724F101"
#   .. ..$ value               :List of 1
#   .. .. ..$ : chr "1246613"
#   .. ..$ shrsOrPrnAmt        :List of 2
#   .. .. ..$ sshPrnamt    :List of 1
#   .. .. .. ..$ : chr "2622406"
#   .. .. ..$ sshPrnamtType:List of 1
#   .. .. .. ..$ : chr "SH"
#   .. ..$ investmentDiscretion:List of 1
#   .. .. ..$ : chr "SOLE"
#   .. ..$ votingAuthority     :List of 3
#   .. .. ..$ Sole  :List of 1
#   .. .. .. ..$ : chr "2622406"
#   .. .. ..$ Shared:List of 1
#   .. .. .. ..$ : chr "0"
#   .. .. ..$ None  :List of 1
#   .. .. .. ..$ : chr "0"
#   ..$ infoTable:List of 7
```

I'm not certain offhand how to extract the front-matter, I hope this is a good enough start.

Comment: Thanks. very usefull. I manage to get the data with      `data_df <- xmlToDataFrame(paste(txt[110:718], collapse = ""))`